# Vaadin 7 embed Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gwt, vaadin

I can't manage to show the google map on my vaadin UI.
I followed [this](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/2971952/2975500) post from the Vaadin forum but i can't understand why in the place where I put the new GMap() extending AbstractJavaScriptComponent it doesn't shows anything.
I placed the four files (GMap.java, GMapState.java, gmap-connector.js, gmap.js) in a dedicated package on the src folder..is this right?
I actually tested the js and it looks like it's reading correctly the content...but it doesn't shows the map.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy one.... i feel stupid now...

```
    this.element.innerHTML = "<div id='map-canvas' style='height:100%; width:100%;'></div>";
```

This do not gets the full free space and the map size came out with width 0px height 0px. So giving it a fixed size solved my problem:

```
    this.element.innerHTML = "<div id='map-canvas' style='height:200px; width:200px;'></div>";
```